# locally held iframe parent location issue

Tags: iframe

So I am holding a html file on my desktop that has an iframe within it.

This iframe is all good but I want a button within it to control the location of the web page hosting it.

So I want the iframe's parent to go back in history by 1 page, I used this method but it did not work. How would you do this?

onClick="parent.history.go(-1)"

Answer (score 0):

If the inner iframe is on a different host that the outer frame (or even two different URL protocols like file: and http:), you will have trouble making a direct call, because the browser is preventing cross-site scripting vulnerabilities.

One thing that works is in that case is cross-window messaging using postMessage().  Check out http://ejohn.org/blog/cross-window-messaging/ for an example.

Comment: hmmm, I hear you - but not sure how I would install this? have a look at this: www.benjaminpotter.org/elog/logbook.html .

The BACK button is the one I'm trying to get to work. Note, I really would love the back button to go to: url:index.html but yeah no idea how to use the cross window messaging... sorry, I'm easily confused.